# Append a p with submitted text and update it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing on jQuery, in this exercise I have to add a p element to the DOM on submit and on every submit I just have to replace the text without delete the p. I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

This is what i was trying to do:

```
if(jQuery('form').find('p')){
  jQuery('<p>' + textToInsert + '</p>').appendTo('form');
} else{
  jQuery('p').empty().text(textToInsert);
}
```

Comment: You add the `<p>` element to the DOM with a unique ID. Whenever you submit the form, check if that ID exists. If not, append it. Otherwise, use `.text()` or `.html()` to replace its content.

Comment: Where is your submit event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/6g161htz/

```js
var textToInsert = "Appended newly";
if(jQuery('form').find('p').length){
  jQuery('p').empty().text(textToInsert);
} else {
  jQuery('<p>' + textToInsert + '</p>').appendTo('form');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  
</form>
```

Check for the length of the element.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Zer0 Welcome buddy :)